# what's the naming scheme of smali file

Tags: android, smali

I'm really obfuscated by the naming of smali file.

Traditionally, the class `a` will be named as `a.smali`, and the inner class `b` of `a` will be named `a$b.smali`.

but just now I came across a class `f`, its file is `f.2.smali`, meanwhile in the same directory I also see a lot of files like `a.2.smali`, `b.2.smali`..., and their similarity is in the directory, `A.smali`,`B.smali` also exist (following is the screenshot of the directory):

[image: Smali file name example]

So I'm curious is there any standard rule that can tell how the smali file name when decompile an Android application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Accidently I found that this situation happens in my Mac OS system, where `A.smali` and `a.smali` are the same file.

when in the other Linux system like Debian, it will not happen, `A.smali` and `a.smali` are different files and the `a.smali` will not become `a.2.smali`.